# Install Ubuntu over network on blank HD

Tags: system-installation

I'm curious if it's possible to install Ubuntu on a blank HD over the network. This is an HP windows home/media server (hp ex490), with no CD/DVD rom. The server doesn't seem to respond to a USB monitor, keyboard or mouse.

I feel like there's information out there already on this, but I come up empty on Google.

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation on how to install Ubuntu over network? It's located here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

Comment: Thanks @NikolaPetkanski, I looked there first and it does provide a lot of useful information, although I wasn't able to find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To do that you will need another PC connected to the same network as your other PC, so on your PC which you have Windows install on (I presume) use [Tftpd32](http://www.jounin.net/download/Tftpd32-4.50-setup.exe) it's a DHCP and network booting daemon.

- Download [Grub4dos](http://grub4dos-chenall.googlecode.com/files/grub4dos-0.4.5b-2011-10-30.7z).
- Set tftpd32 to have grldr as boot file.
- Download plop boot manager (google is your best bet).
- On the client PC set it to a PXE-boot or network boot.
- Turn off dhcpd from your router of you're using it.
- Boot the old-pc.
- Once your in grub, select command line.

Type in :

```
map --mem (pd)/plpbt.img (fd0)
map --hook
root (fd0)
chainloader +1
boot
```

Then you'll be in plop boot manager and you'll be able to boot from usb from now on.